# Что не так с STL (по мнениию Торвальдса)?

Tags: c++, c

Из-за чего Линус Торвальдс так не возлюбил STL ?

Просто любопытно:

> C++ приводит к очень, очень плохим проектным решениям. Неизбежно
> начинают применяться «замечательные» библиотечные возможности вроде
> **STL**, и Boost, и прочего мусора, которые могут «помочь»
> программированию, но порождают:  — невыносимую боль, когда они не
> работают (и всякий, кто утверждает, что **STL** и особенно Boost стабильны
> и портируемы, настолько погряз во лжи, что это даже не смешно)  —
> неэффективно абстрагированные программные модели, когда спустя два
> года обнаруживается, что какая-то абстракция была недостаточно
> эффективна, но теперь весь код зависит ото всех окружающих её
> замечательных объектных моделей, и её нельзя исправить, не переписав
> всё приложение. Другими словами, единственный способ иметь хороший,
> эффективный, низкоуровневый и портируемый C++ сводится к тому, чтобы
> ограничиться всеми теми вещами, которые элементарно доступны в Си.

Лично я под использованием STL в большинстве случаев понимаю использование контейнеров: std::vector, std::list, std::deque и std::string(c оговорками). Что с ними может быть не так, с точки зрения Торвальдса ?

Comment: Это не мнение, а (подходящее английское выражение) rant, где Линус, как обычно, ругается в адрес вещей, которые ему непонятны.

Comment: Линусу просто не нравится то, что с++ прячет часть сложности, но за это приходится платить. А иногда слишком много. Та же move семантика (которую, как мы знаем тут 90% посетителей этого сайта совсем не понимают), в си элементарно реализуется через обычные указатели (и все "идеально перемещается"). Другое дело, что нужно очень внимательно следить за тем, кто будет освобождать память (а вот это может быть иногда очень нетривиально). Линус умеет следить за своей памятью. А вот большинство пользователей - нет.

Comment: [EWD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0,_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5) же, вообще обобщил -- [C++ damages the brain …](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/)

Comment: @avp, там по Вашей ссылке есть одна заметка https://assoc.tumblr.com/post/411601680/performance-of-stl-vector-vs-plain-c-arrays - "Производительность вектора STL по сравнению с обычными массивами C" - она кажется ну очень странной, если я правильно понял, то сравнивают вектор с обычным массивом объявленным на стеке.

Comment: @Optimus1, возможно сейчас (с новыми CPU и продвинутыми по сравнению с 2010 г. компайлерами) это уже не актуально. При желании можете сами перепроверить. В любом случае (хоть о Линусе, хоть о Дейкстре, хоть о каком другом критике того же масштаба говорить),  речь идет не об эффективности маленьких программ (или локализованных участков кода). По сути надо говорить об эффективности всей разработки (включая поддержку и стоимость повторного использования наработок в др. проектах). Суть критики в том, что С++ слишком сложен.